# Distinguish empty macro definition from 0

Tags: macros, definition, c-preprocessor

I need to distinguish the three forms:

`#define CONSTANTNAME`

`#define CONSTANTNAME 0`

`#define CONSTANTNAME 1`

I saw someone use the hint:

`#if (CONSTANTNAME - 0)`

but this confuse the form without value and the one with 0.

Is there something smarter?

Comment: Please tag with relevant programming language(s)

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume you want the empty definition and the `1` definition to be equivalent with the `0` is the different one? I'm pretty sure that question already exists on stackoverflow, but I can't find it.

Here's a usenet thread on the same topic: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/jkI2vz8ZxmE/1-kOKCQ2MrwJ

Several answers are given there. The cleverest one looks like:

```
#if -CONSTANTNAME+1 == 1
... the "no CONSTANTNAME" branch
#else
... the "yes CONSTANTNAME" branch
#endif
```

If `CONSTANTNAME` is empty, `-+1 == 1` => false.

If it's `1`, `-1+1 == 1` => false.

If it's `0`, `-0+1 == 1` => true.

If it's not defined, the default cpp replacement for unrecognized tokens applies, and that's a `0` so it's true.

**UPDATE**

If you want 3 branches, you can still use the `-FOO+0 == 1` test and add an extra test like `FOO+0==0`. Look at the results you can get:

```
Value of `FOO`   `-FOO+1==1`   `FOO+0==0`
 empty string         false         true
            1         false        false
            0          true         true
```

If the 4th case, macro not defined, is interesting, it must be tested with `#ifdef FOO` or `defined(FOO)` since it is otherwise indistinguishable from `0`.

Sample code:

```
#if !defined(FOO)
... handle undef
#elif -FOO+1 == 1
... handle 0
#elif FOO+0 == 0
... handle empty
#else
... handle 1
#endif
```

Comment: I need to follow three different branches for the three cases listed in question